# CSS Transform flickering on chrome and IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I'm attempting to make a div appear by having it hidden forced via `rotate` and `backface-visibility.` The issue is that it is flickering and then disappears after a second. This happens on Chrome. On IE11 it is not appearing at all...

http://jsfiddle.net/1xq96btg/

It's working fine on Firefox.

EDIT: I'm using just `backface-visibilty` on its own as when I included its variants it became even more unstable and strange behaving.

EDIT 2: `z-index` doesn't seem to be helping either.

HTML

```
<div class="one-third-box" onclick="location.href='#'">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/image/jpg" />
    <div class="box-description">this is a test description</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.one-third-box {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-right: 0.2%;
    width: 33.2%;
    position:relative;
    perspective: 1000;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.one-third-box:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.one-third-box:hover img {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter:"FlipH";
    position:relative;
    top:-1px;
}
.one-third-box:hover .overlay {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.box-description {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2f5d70;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    height: 38%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 6%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url('images/overlay.png');
}
.one-third-box > img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by changing the CSS a bit...okay, a lot.
I'm assuming that this was being caused by inconsistent hardware acceleration between the overlapping elements and/or that `transform-style: preserve-3d;` line. Either way, I've created a snippet that seems to work for me. I also chose to go with a CSS animation instead of a transition because it just makes it that much more readable in this case.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; } /* Simple CSS reset */

.one-third-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 33.2%;
}

.one-third-box > img {
  transform-style: flat;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* Fixes blur from scaling */
}

.box-description {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2f5d70;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  height: 38%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-top: 6%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

/* ---------------------- Hover effects ---------------------- */
.one-third-box:hover > img,
.one-third-box:hover > .box-description {
  -webkit-animation: flip 0.6s;
  animation: flip 0.6s;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* flip animation */
@-webkit-keyframes flip {
  from { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
  to { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
}
@keyframes flip {
  from { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
  to { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="one-third-box" onclick="location.href='#'">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <img src="http://www.surgemedia.ie/portfolio-images/alci-clear.png" />
  <div class="box-description">this is a test description</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :), I was beginning to tear my hair out on that, and was overcomplicating things! This solution is working great